# Using Proximity Sensor in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean, proximitysensor

I was working on proximity sensor in S4. After update to 4.3 my application started getting crashed.

Here is the code Sample :

This method is written in a service class

```
public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    // Play song
    try {
        Log.d("Debug","playSong 1");
        mp.reset();

        Log.d("Debug","playSong 2");
        mp.setDataSource(songsListingSD.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));

        Log.d("Debug","playSong 3");
        mp.prepare();

        Log.d("Debug","playSong 4");
        mp.start();

        // Displaying Song title
        Log.d("Debug","playSong 5");
        String songTitle = songsListingSD.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        Log.d("Debug","playSong songTitle = " + songTitle);
        Log.d("Debug","playSong 6");
        songTitleLabel.get().setText(songTitle);
        Log.d("Debug","playSong 7");
        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.get().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause); // :351
        Log.d("Debug","playSong 8");
        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.get().setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.get().setMax(100);
        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have implemented the service class with SensorEventListener interface and implemented the abstract method.

Here is the code :

```
         public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Log.d("Player Service", "service called for sensor event, Next called1");
    try{
          Log.d("Debug"," check Here");

         Random rand = new Random();
      Log.d("Debug","sensor method 1");
      currentSongIndex = rand
            . nextInt((songsListingSD.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
    Log.d("Debug","sensor method 2");
    Log.d("Debug"," Cur Index = " + currentSongIndex);
    playSong(currentSongIndex);
    Log.d("Debug","sensor method 3");
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 }
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 }
```

This is the stack Trace :

```
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Player Service(19444): service called for sensor event, Next called1
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Debug(19444):  check Here
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Debug(19444): sensor method 1
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Debug(19444): sensor method 2
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Debug(19444):  Cur Index = 2
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Debug(19444): playSong 1
10-29 01:09:29.546: D/Debug(19444): playSong 2
10-29 01:09:29.576: D/Debug(19444): playSong 3
10-29 01:09:29.585: D/Debug(19444): playSong 4
10-29 01:09:29.596: D/Debug(19444): playSong 5
10-29 01:09:29.596: D/Debug(19444): playSong songTitle = [SongsPK.info] Aashiqui 2 - 01 -   Tum Hi Ho
10-29 01:09:29.596: D/Debug(19444): playSong 6
10-29 01:09:29.596: W/System.err(19444): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 01:09:29.596: W/System.err(19444):    at         com.example.audionplayerinservice.PlayerService.playSong(PlayerService.java:351)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at   com.example.audionplayerinservice.PlayerService.onSensorChanged(PlayerService.java:589)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:371)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-29 01:09:29.606: W/System.err(19444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-29 01:09:29.616: W/System.err(19444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code to register the proximity listener :

```
    private WeakReference<ImageView> btnPlay
    private WeakReference<TextView> songTitleLabel;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL );
```

I am testing this in emulator 4.3 (Android) . If I comment the sensor part then the app is working. 
Please help me in debugging as I don't able to find any error.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is btnPlay variable?

Comment: weakRef of imageview, image is there and I said same code is working if I just disable the Sensor part

Comment: i think its not sensor related problem as the exception is at the playSong function.

Comment: But then Y its working correctly when I disable the sensor part. More over U can see the stack that I am getting the value and the image is also present there. Does this issue is the cause of restricted profile? I don't know about restricted profile at all

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation for [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#get%28%29). 
There is no guarantee that `WeakReference` get() method always returns `ImageView`. when System calls garbage collector, ImageView in WeakReference can be cleared as ImageView has WeakReference. when ImageView has garbage collected, get() method returns simply `null`.
So do null check like

```
     ImageView imageView = btnPlay.get();
     if(imageView != bull) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
     }
```

Comment: I checked, its getting null there but y? Any specific reason? Same code is working with android 4.1.2 ,4.2.2. When testing on 4.3 I am getting this error. Any way to resolve this? And still y its working when I disable the sensor part? any explanation ?

Comment: it purely depends on Dalvik machine implementation. from latest android, DVM is very effective and WeakReferences has less chances to hold its object...

Comment: But if it was issue with that then it should not be running when I disable the sensor part....

Comment: We can not say when weak reference is garbage collected...
so go for other alternatives...

Comment: service class, in Activity all objects are present.I am referencing to the main activity objects..

Comment: then why to go for WeakReferences? try establishing communication between Activity and Service using ServiceConnectionListener

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40160/discussion-between-jeet-and-gopal-rao)